# bison/c++: operator+ cannot be found, but 'add' function can?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, bison

I have a weird problem when I use operator overloads in my bison parser rules, they cannot be found but functions right next to the overloads works 100% just fine. I suspect that I am missing something specific to either operator overloads or bison specifically

EDIT: Minimized the example and made it reproducible

### Mimimal Example Code

I apologise if this seems like a lot, but flex/bison in C++ mode is difficult to get as small as possible. This example can only add integers together.

src/scanner.l

```
%{
#include "driver.h"
%}
%option noyywrap
%{
  yy::parser::symbol_type make_NUMBER(const std::string &s, const yy::parser::location_type& loc);
%}

int   [0-9]+
blank [ \t\r]

%%
%{
    yy::location& loc = drv.location;
    loc.step();
%}

{blank}+   loc.step();
\n+        loc.lines(yyleng); loc.step();
"+"        return yy::parser::make_PLUS   (loc);
{int}      return make_NUMBER(yytext, loc);
.          { throw yy::parser::syntax_error(loc, "invalid character: " + std::string(yytext)); }
<<EOF>>    return yy::parser::make_YYEOF (loc);
%%

yy::parser::symbol_type make_NUMBER(const std::string &s, const yy::parser::location_type& loc) {
  errno = 0;
  long n = strtol (s.c_str(), NULL, 10);
  if (! (INT_MIN <= n && n <= INT_MAX && errno != ERANGE))
    throw yy::parser::syntax_error (loc, "integer is out of range: " + s);
  return yy::parser::make_NUMBER ((int) n, loc);
}

void driver::scan_begin() {
    yy_flex_debug = false;
    yy_scan_string(file.c_str());
}

void driver::scan_end() {}
```

src/parser.y

```
%header
%language "c++"
%define api.token.constructor
%define api.value.type variant

%code requires {
    #include <variant>
    using symbol_value_t = std::variant<int>;
    symbol_value_t add(const symbol_value_t& a, const symbol_value_t& b);
    symbol_value_t operator+(const symbol_value_t& a, const symbol_value_t& b);
    class driver;
}
%param { driver& drv }
%locations
%code {
    #include "driver.h"
}
%token
  PLUS    "+"
;

%token <int> NUMBER "number"
%nterm <symbol_value_t> exp

%%
%start unit;
unit: exp { std::cout << std::get<int>($1) << std::endl; };

exp:
  "number"      { $$ = $1; }
| exp "+" exp   { $$ = add($1,$3); }
| "(" exp ")"   { $$ = $2; }
%%

void yy::parser::error (const location_type& l, const std::string& m) {
  std::cerr << l << ": " << m << '\n';
}

symbol_value_t add(const symbol_value_t& a, const symbol_value_t& b) {
    return std::get<int>(a) + std::get<int>(b);
}
symbol_value_t operator+(const symbol_value_t& a, const symbol_value_t& b) {
    return add(a,b);
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int res = 0;
    driver drv;
    for (int i = 1; i < argc; ++i)
        drv.parse(argv[i]);
    return res;
}
```

src/driver.h

```cpp
#include <string>
#include "parser.hpp"
#define YY_DECL yy::parser::symbol_type yylex (driver& drv)
YY_DECL;

struct driver {
    driver() = default;
    int parse(const std::string& f) {
        file = f;
        scan_begin();
        yy::parser parse(*this);
        int res = parse();
        scan_end();
        return res;
    }
    std::string file;
    void scan_begin();
    void scan_end();
    yy::location location;
};
```

CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)
project(expr VERSION 0.1.0)
find_package(FLEX REQUIRED)
find_package(BISON REQUIRED)
set (CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
BISON_TARGET(expr_parser src/parser.y ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/parser.cpp)
FLEX_TARGET(expr_scanner src/scanner.l ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/scanner.cpp)
ADD_FLEX_BISON_DEPENDENCY(expr_scanner expr_parser)
include_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR} src)
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME}
        ${BISON_expr_parser_OUTPUTS}
        ${FLEX_expr_scanner_OUTPUTS}
        )
```

#### Compile it with:

```sh
mkdir bin && cd bin
cmake ..
make
```

#### Run it with:

```sh
./expr "3+3"
```

## The problem

If you were to try to use the `+`-operator overload for `symbol_value_t` defined in `symboltable.h/cpp` like so:

src/parser.y

```
...
| exp "+" exp   { $$ =$1 + $3; } // Use operator+ instead of add() function
...
```

The compiler complains about not being able to find `operator+(const symbol_value_t&, const symbol_value_t&)`, which is odd, since it gladly accepts `add`

I have a similar problem (assuming it's the same underlying problem) with defining `operator<<(ostream&, symbol_value_t&)`. I feel like I am missing something blindingly obvious here.

Comment: "snippet" and "placeholder implementation" means that no-one here can reproduce your problem. It also means that the problem might well be hiding in the part you left out. Like, did you set `%language "c++"`? Please try to come up with a [mcve].

Comment: A [mcve] should also be a single file in most cases, maybe even two in this case. Also, both expected and actual output are required. Further, the commands for compiling and generating code.

Comment: All other things aside, you may be interested in [Boost.Spirit](http://boost-spirit.com/home/), which offers parser generation directly in C++ itself.

Comment: ADL strikes again. "Name lookup rules make it impractical to declare operators in global or user-defined namespace that operate on types from the std namespace, e.g. a custom operator>> or operator+ for std::vector or for std::pair (unless the element types of the vector/pair are user-defined types, which would add their namespace to ADL). Such operators would not be looked up from template instantiations..." [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl).

Comment: Thank you so much @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. ! I fixed my issue by defining `symbol_value_t` as a struct inheriting from `std::variant` instead of defining it through a `using`-directive.

This was the resource I needed!